# Why did the SO team stop using log4net?

Tags: discussion, development

Early in development the SO team encountered some problems with the logging framework log4net (mentioned in a podcast, but not fully explained as I recall).  In a blog post Jeff said they stopped using it, but didn't elaborate.  What exactly were those problems and with what did they replace log4net?

Comment: I'm not a member of the SO dev team, but sheesh; I've seen graphical libraries that are less complicated. In the end, we settled on the Trace functionality from the .NET Framework. Simple, to the point, and gets the job done.

Comment: @Robert - whew...I'm not the only person who finds Log4Net overly complicated

Comment: I think log4net's rep as being complicated stems from overkill in the config files that people end up using as a starting point.  If you've got a leaned out config, its pretty straightforward.  Unfortunately almost all of the examples are bloated as f__k.